# Problema al crear multiples switch apartir de un array en react

Tags: array, reactjs, switch

tengo un formulario de preguntas en el cual puse multiples switch ya que las respuestas son si o no.

Al crearlo la logica funciona(se registra true y false por console.log) pero los switchs se mueven todos juntos para true y para false.`introducir el código aquí`

perdon pense que asi se iba a ver mejor, ahi paso el codigo.

````
>aca esta la funcion 

```
      const [responses, setResponses] = React.useState([]);
      const [resp, setResp] = React.useState(true);
      const setResps = (id, valor) => {
        setResp(valor);
        const newResponses = [...responses];
        setResp(valor);
        newResponses[id] = { id_question: id, value: resp };
        setResponses(newResponses);
        console.log(responses);
      }
````

```
>esta parte es la renderizacion del form con los switch
```

````
<Forms onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              {question.map((questions, index) => (
                <li key={question.id_question}>
                  <List>
                    <ListItem primary={questions.question} height="medium" 
                  />
                  </List>
                  <div className="check">
                    <div>
                      
           <Switch label="This is a switch" onChange={() => 
            setResps(questions.order, (!resp))} className="demo- 
  checkbox"         
           checked={!resp} />
                    </div>
                    {`Value is ${!resp}`}
                  </div>
                </li>
              ))}
       ```
````

Creo que el error viene por el lado del array(question) ya que en ningún momento actualizo su estado.trate de hacerlo pero me da error.

muchas gracias

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a stackOverflow en español! Por favor no utilices imágenes con código, cuándo formúlas tus preguntas tienes las herramientas para compartir el código de manera correcta, revisa [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `resp` es un único boolean en tu código, pero tienes un array para la lista. Entonces cada vez que usas el Switch todos los swiches se van a actualizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como escribí en el comentario, `resp` es un único boolean, pero necesitas un boolean para cada pregunta.

Aquí tienes una solución:
https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-bush-nx8cm?file=/src/App.js

Puse el Switch como un componente propio con su propio estado. Uso un simple Switch, pero puedes usar tu Switch componente en lugar de `<label>` y `<input>`.

```
export const Switch = (props) => {
  const [resp, setResp] = React.useState(props.respuesta);
  return (
    <label className="switch">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={resp}
        onChange={() => {
          setResp(!resp);
          props.actualizar(!resp);
        }}
      />
      <span className="slider round" />
    </label>
  );
};
```

Comment: gracias por la respuestas, entiendo casi todo solo tengo unas dudas.
const [preguntas, setPreguntas] = React.useState(question);
console.log(preguntas)
no m e trae nada ya que question viene de otro componen traido por apicall. No se si tengo que hacer alguna llamada especial para este caso, como utilizar componentWillReceiveProps ya qu enunca lo utilice. gracias

Comment: Okay, que recibes cuando escribes `console.log(question)`? (porque tienes `question.map((questions, index)....`)

Comment: claro, si escribo console.log(question) recibo toda la info. pero si lo pongo como vos haces.
const [preguntas, setPreguntas] = React.useState(question); 
console.log(preguntas)
eh imprimo preguntas me sale vacio

Comment: ah okay, si question cambia puedes usar useEffect. `React.useEffect(() => { setPreguntas(question); }, [question])`. Esta función va a actualizar cada vez que question se actualize.

Comment: Mil Gracias Milmal, lo pude solucionar con tu ayuda, gracias por la gran mano, el useEffect me sirvió de maravilla. 
Sos un genio nunca se me hubiera ocurrido setear dentro del switch.
abrazo grande.